# How to handle audio streams and mixing for VoIP

Tags: java, audio, bandwidth, mixing

We're working on a Java based Voice over IP program, and we need to find an effective way of keeping streams and server side stress to a reasonable amount. We're writing this for a multiplayer game, and we plan to have a few different modes for determining how to mix and send out audio. We plan on having it "Opt In" to keep useless streams out of the equation, if they choose not to participate in voice chat. Aside from that, we're thinking channels, private chat (2 people), and proximity. If we were using a channel with 16+ people in it, we want to find if there is a way to avoid the x^2 number of streams (256 in this case). We also need to try to keep client side work to a reasonable level, as it will be running a game. We're not too sure how much work a large server could handle, as it will be exponential as more people are in a channel. We may need to limit the amount of people per channel, or allow the server owner to do that, as well as limit the number of channels. This game can have around 40-500 people on a server at once, depending on the popularity, and we're unsure of how to handle that type of stress on a server's processing and bandwidth.

Essentially, we're asking if anyone has any knowledge of existing systems that have an efficient way of handling this. We're using JSpeex for our audio encoding if that's of any relevance. So, are there any methods out there for handling this, or possibly even some ideas from the community? We also plan on re-implementing this in a smaller scale Skype like program that we've been developing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you would need 256 streams.  You shouldn't be going direct from client to client.

For each client you need a single two way connection to the server.  All input/output audio is directed through the server.  The server than multiplexes all the audio a player is to receive into a single audio stream and forwards it along.

When you are in a private chat, the server simply only forwards packets from the other player in the private chat with you.

When using proximity, the server multiplexes audio from any player in range into a single stream.

I would assume any decent audio encoding package would have support for multiplexing audio together from multiple channels, but I don't know anything about JSpeex.

Comment: 256 streams being trafficked through the server. x^2 streams, because we need to distribute audio to every person, from every person, excluding your own audio (echo). If we had a way to "mute" their own audio upon returning, we would only need x streams. Its a mixing type of thing, and we're unsure of how to handle it.

Comment: That's what I'm saying.  You don't need an individual stream from/to every person.  You just need the server to multiplex the input from each person together.  So each user just needs a single input and a single output channel.  The server just needs to be smart.  It's obviously not gonna include any echo audio.

Comment: We planned on having only one socket connection per client. We're purely talking about streams in the server's processing. Not sure if I'm missing something, but the output being sent to each client will be multiplexed. I apologize if I'm just entirely missing something.

Comment: Right but there should only be a single output stream to each player and a single input stream from each player.  The server should be combining the audio into a single stream unique to each client and then forwarding it.

Comment: Exactly my point. Meaning, we need to split the input streams, and distribute them accordingly for each individual person connected. 16 people connected means 16 in, 16 out, but we need to create duplicates to create the output streams per user. Meaning, x^2 streams on the server. If there's a way to do this without duplicating before mixing, I'd love to find that out.

Comment: Nevermind, I had a really stupid moment. You're right. Had trouble thinking about it, as my developer is doing this, and I'm not. I wasn't thinking about the byte array being sent out to each individual person. Rather, I was thinking "There's a stream, and it has to get to multiple people. Have to split it". Thanks for your help!